# multiply ng-view in bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, navigation, angular-routing

I have a index.html page with **page-header**, **navigation-bar**, **page-body** sections (DIVs).

I use angular routing for change the content of the page-body section.

Now what I want to implement is to change the the content of the navigation-bar and page-body at same time, from a controller.

My scenario is:
Login content is displayed in the page-body section. After the successful login request I want to switch two contents somehow at same time:

- the menu which locates between the navigation-bar div element
- the application body content, locates in page-body div element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ng-route`, you should take a look at [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). It allows you to define multiple views in your page.